# The name of the given podspec `FlutterToast` doesn't match the expected one `fluttertoast` flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages

I imported the `fluttertoast` package in my flutter project.

I added dependencies in `.yaml` file and within my project with `import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';` but when I run the code on Simulator this is the output :

```
   -> Fetching podspec for `fluttertoast` from `.symlinks/plugins/fluttertoast/ios`
[!] The name of the given podspec `FlutterToast` doesn't match the expected one `fluttertoast`
```

I tried to change the name from `FlutterToast` to `fluttertoast`to match the name but it didn't work.

I also cleaned the workspace and deleted the `.pub-cache`...I tried a lots of stuffs but nothing worked.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same issue. Problem was in pubspec.yml I had plugin dependency added like this (Without any version number):

```
fluttertoast:
```

Seems latest version is (5.0.1) is causing this issue. So changing the dependency to following, fixed the issue for me:

```
fluttertoast: 4.0.1
```